# Disable deletion of a base entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Here is a simple entity model:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class Base {
}

@Entity
class Derived extends Base {
}
```

When I delete a derived entity, Hibernate automatically deletes records from both tables (base and derived). But I need to force Hibernate to delete a derived row only, and to keep a row in a base table untouched, because it should be deleted on a database level.

I tried to add the following [rule](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-update.html):

```sql
CREATE RULE base_delete AS ON DELETE TO derived
DO DELETE FROM base WHERE id = OLD.id;
```

It works fine on a database level. When I delete a derived row, the base row is deleted as well. But when I delete a derived entity using Hibernate I get the following exception: "org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)"

I also tried to use a trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_base()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM base WHERE id = OLD.id;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER delete_base
AFTER DELETE ON derived
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION delete_base();
```

It works as expected on a database level. But Hibernate throws the exception: "org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: delete from base where id=?"

So the question is the following. If I already delete a row from a base table using a rule or trigger, is it possible to prevent Hibernate from deletion of that row again?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple soultion, just override DELETE-statements for both classes:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@SQLDelete(sql = "DELETE from base WHERE id=? AND FALSE")
abstract class Base {
}

@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "DELETE from derived WHERE id=?")
class Derived extends Base {
}
```

Probably another one is to define a custom DeleteEventListener.